# Vue-Budget-Calculator-App: dynamic route related props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vue-router

### Budget-Calculator-App

I am working on a Budget-Calculator-App which should allow users to filter there salary with  a self defined list of expenses to see the remaining budget they have after all expenses and incomes will be calculated with the salary.

Preview Image:

[image: app preview]

---

## How it works:

I use the LocalStorage of Chrome to save store.state.users like this example:

```js
  state: {
    users: [
      {
        userName: 'John',
        salary: 2000,
        leftover: 0,
        inc: [],
        exp: [],
        active: false,
      }
    ],
  }
```

This works so far. The data is stored in memory as intended.
For every added user there will be created a dynamic route related to it's `users[id]`

[image: works correct]

---

### Where i am stuck:

I am creating the dynamic routes like this. In component **Navigation.vue** check the code below for **'CHECK HERE'** to find the part in `<router-link>`:

```js
<template>
  <!-- TODO: maybe remove the border-bottom -->
  <div
    id="navigation"
    class="border-bottom"
  >
    <!-- MODAL FOR CHANGE USER SETTINGS AND ADD NEW USER -->
    <UserSettingsModal />
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <a
        class="navbar-brand"
        href="#"
      >
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary modal-btn"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#user-modal"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-user-cog" />
          <!-- <i class="fas fa-plus position-absolute" /> -->
        </button>
      </a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" />
      </button>
      <div
        id="navbarNav"
        class="collapse navbar-collapse"
      >
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <router-link to="/">
            <li>
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                href="#"
              >Home</a>
            </li>
          </router-link>
          <!-- TODO: PASS EACH USERS.ID{} TO THE HIS ROUTE, IF POSSIBLE -->
          <!-- CHECK HERE -->
          <router-link
            v-for="user in users"
            :key="user.userName"
            class="nav-item"
            :to="{ name: 'User', params: { userId: users.indexOf(user) }}"
          >
            <li>
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                href="#"
                @click="toggleActive(user.userName)"
              >{{ user.userName }}</a>
            </li>
          </router-link>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import UserSettingsModal from './UserSettingsModal.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    UserSettingsModal
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['users'])
  },
  mounted() {
    //TODO: this part should load the active user from state
    console.log(this.users);
  },
  methods: {
    // TODO: for this, check the todo in store
    toggleActive(userToToggleActive) {
      let usersArr = this.$store.state.users;
      console.log(userToToggleActive);
      
      // WAY: 1
      // let indexOf = usersArr.findIndex(user => {
      //   console.log(user.userName);
        
      //   user.userName == userToToggleActive;
      // });

      // WAY: 2

      for (let i = 0; i < usersArr.length; usersArr++) {
        const user = usersArr[i];
        console.log(user);
        
        
      }

      // console.log(indexOf);
      



      // console.log(userToToggleActive);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#navigation {
  .navbar {
    .fa-user-cog {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: $white;
    }
    .fa-user-cog:hover {
      color: $orange;
    }
    .modal-btn {
      background-color: $dark !important;
    }
    // .fa-plus {
    //   color: #000000;
    //   top: 15px;
    //   left: 50px;
    // }
    .active {
      color: $orange !important;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

The router it self i did like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Welcome from '../views/Welcome.vue';
import User from '../components/User/_User.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Welcome',
    component: Welcome
  },
  {
    path: '/user/:userId',
    name: 'User',
    component: User,
    props: true
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  // mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

This is how `User.vue` looke like, the props are ready to be filled with the data:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <UserInfo />
    <UserIncExp />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserInfo from '../User/UserInfo.vue';
import UserIncExp from '../User/UserIncExp/_UserIncExp.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    UserInfo,
    UserIncExp
  },
  props: {
    userName: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    salary: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    inc: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    exp: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      userId: this.$route.params.user
    }
  },
  created() {
    
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

---

### What i expect:

I want to fill the routes and all instances of the created `User.vue` filled dynamically with there related data from the LocalStorage.

If i switch the route, then it should change the content.
The `{ userName }` one bracket is just a placeholder for visualization, there need to be the actual data from the LocalStorage
At the moment it is like this:

[image: what i expect]

Comment: instead of passing data from props in your user component you can get the data from `localStorage` in your `User.vue` component and find the user by route id and display it in your template.

Comment: @ajuni880 how you mean that? how can i find the users by route id? by eval. the url? or is there a rel. documentation in vue?

Comment: Here you can check the docs https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html